# If is ok but else is not

Tags: php, mysql

i'm a beginner when it comes to PHP & MYSQL
and while learning stuff i made this piece of code.

```
if (filter_var("$mail", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    while ($data = $response->fetch()) {    
        $count = $data->rowCount();
        if (!empty($count)) {
            echo 'Already Registered<BR />';
            echo '<a href="test.php">back</a>';
        }else {
            echo 'new user';
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'EMAIL NOT VALID';
}
$response->closeCursor();
```

Everything works fine except when $count is empty it doesn't trigger the statement i made.
Any ideas? thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `while` block will only be entered if there are results fetched. You should test rowCount() BEFORE fetching.